# How Can I Split a String According To Delimiters in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am trying to split a string according to delimiter
the equevelant code in C# is :

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
String[] query = sometext.Split(delimiterChars);
```

but I want to do it in Qt

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [split](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split) function that accepts [Qt Regular Expression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html).

```
QRegExp rx("(\\ |\\,|\\.|\\:|\\t)"); //RegEx for ' ' or ',' or '.' or ':' or '\t'
QStringList query = sometext.split(rx);
```